# Discretize PDE using SymPy

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python

I am trying to discretize the following PDE (but in 2D) to have a numerical solution, using any method. But I will not soon understand the mathematics involved and so.

$$  \underbrace{\rho_t  c_t  \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}}_{\substack{\text{rate of temperature} \\ \text{changes}}}
  =
  \overbrace{\nabla \cdot (k_t \nabla T)}^{\substack{\text{heat conduction } \\ \text{in the tissue}}}
  -
  \underbrace{\rho_b c_b w_b (T-T_b) }_{\substack{\text{advection by perfusing} \\ \text{blood (cooling source)}}}
  +
  \overbrace{Q_m}^{\substack{\text{methabolic} \\ \text{heating}}}
  +
  \underbrace{P}_{\substack{\text{energy dissipation by} \\ \text{the MNPs (heat source)}}}$$

I'm programming a solver in Python for this one, but I need the discretization of it. Then it occurs to me that I could do it with sympy, only I can't do it if I use it very well. Until then, this is what I have.

```
from sympy.interactive import printing

printing.init_printing(use_latex=True)
import sympy as sym
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, Del


T_a = sym.Symbol("T_b")
k = sym.Symbol("k")
rho_t = sym.Symbol("rho_t")
rho_b = sym.Symbol("rho_b")
c_t = sym.Symbol("c_t")
c_b = sym.Symbol("c_b")
w_b = sym.Symbol("w_b")
q_m = sym.Symbol("q_m")
P_m = sym.Symbol("P_m")


x,y,t=sym.symbols('x y t', real=True)

T = sym.Function("T")(x,y,t)
f = sym.Function("f")(T,t)
h = sym.Function("h")(k,T,t)

f_ddt = f.diff(T, t)
h_ddt_xy = k * (h.diff(T, x,2) + h.diff(T, y,2))

eq = sym.Eq(f_ddt, h_ddt_xy - rho_b * c_b * w_b * (Ta - T) + q_m + P_m)
```

The problem is to solve the temperature distribution of tissue that was inyected with nanoparticles, in contact with other that dosn't have the nanoparticles (same equation but without `P_m`). This ecuation is known as **Pennes Bioheat equation**.

I have build a mesh for my problem and compute `P_m`  for every node of the tissue with nanoparticle, as `P_m` its not a diferential equation.

In this figure the 1/4 of ellipse is the tissue with nanoparticles and P_m values.

[image]

But now I need to solve the differential part of the equation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What kind of PDE is that?

Comment: To give an example of what the Community Bot means, have you found this code's results seem unrealistic?